# How to do string comparison with string literals?

Tags: c++, if-statement

i am having problem in checking whether variable value matches or not. i am using if statement to check whether health variable is having excellent as value or not but the below code gives error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class person {
private:
    char health[20], city[20], gender[20];
    int age;
public:
    void getdata();
    void dispdata();
};

void person::getdata()
{
    cout <<" Enter the person's health";
    cin >> health;
    cout << "Enter your age";
    cin >> age;
    cout << " Do you live in city";
    cin >> city;
    cout << "Gender: male or female";
    cin >> gender;
}

void person::dispdata()
{
    if(health == 'excellent') {
        cout << "The person can be insured\n";
        cout << "his premium is $4 per thousand and his policy amount cannot exceed Rs. 200,000.";
    } else {
        cout << "Error";
    }
}
int main()
{
    person s1;
    s1.getdata();
    s1.dispdata();
    return 0;
}
```

whenever i use if statement to check whether health is == to excellent it does not work. i even tried using double quotes and single quotes as well.

Comment: you need `strcmp` from `string` library...google it

Comment: The problem in your code is `'excellent'`. Single quote is used to the  character literals, while double quotes are used to string literals.

Comment: Note that single quotes are for character literals, double quotes for string literals,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `strcmp` like functions to compare strings in C++.

```
if(strcmp(health,"excellent")==0)
{
 ...
}
```

In C++ you can not compare strings that are created as `char` arrays with `==` directly and also use `double-qoutes` for strings C++. single quote is for characters.
You can create strings as oblect of `std::string` class and then use overloaded operators to compare strings in C++. read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/)

Comment: that one is working fine. but can you tell me how to check in that field if age is between 24 and 36.

Comment: @rahulkapoor99 where you want to test that condition? age is `int` right so you can directly put one condition to test as 24<=age && age <=36 right? whats the problem?